# Windows 10 Print Screen does not save anything to my clip board

Tags: windows-10, print-screen

Using Windows 10 Professional, build 17134.765, version 1803.

Asked a thousand times I'm sure, and one more time here.

I am aware that `Foo`+`PrintScrn` is supposed to copy the image to my clip board for pasting into GIMP or Paint or Photoshop or whatever.

It's not doing that.

To Reproduce:

1. Try `Anything`+`Print Screen`
2. Open MSPaint
3. Try Ctrl-V
4. GoTo: 1 for every other key.
5. Silently weep...

What do I need to do to make PrintScreen capture the screen data to be pasted into MSPaint or whatever other program I want to use?

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using?  I was unable to reproduce this behavior which tells me you have the software installed that is preventing the shortcut from working

Comment: Updated question. Windows 10 Professional.

Comment: Windows 10 Professional would be the edition you are running not the version.  There is only one shortcut that exists, by the way, it's CTRL+PRINT SCREEN, anything else won't take a screenshot of the current application.  Just Print Screen by itself will take a screenshot of the entire desktop.  *Make sure you are using the correct shortcut.*

Comment: Print Screen does nothing. Ctrl+Print Screen does nothing.

Comment: You actually provided it in your last edit `17134.765`.  **17134** is Windows 10 version 1803.